# Show in lisbtox elements from database using DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datatable, listbox

I`m trying to show elements from my database "Worker" in a listbox in a WPF,I want to do this using a DataTable, I`ve checked that my Datatable contain the elements from the database, the problem is trying to show these elements in the listbox, the listbox doesn`t show anything, it`s just blank. This is my code:

```
  private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
         DataTable mydatatable = GetDataTable();
         listBoxListNames.ItemsSource = mydatatable.ToString();
         listBoxListNames.SelectedValuePath = "id";
         listBoxListNames.DisplayMemberPath = "name".ToString();          
        ShowDatabase();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ListItem instead of just a string, it has a "text" and "value".

For your example:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in mydatatable.Rows)
{
    listBoxListNames.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: It shows me an error: 'ListItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments, I tried deleting one of the arguments but then it shows me other error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph' I need to show the names of workers on my listbox to delete after selecting a name, so I need the ID too in SelectedValuePath because I`ll delete using the "id" not the "name"